# Incremental mapping in velocity template

Tags: java, mapping, velocity

I have got the following velocity template:

```
hi, $name
```

where as my velocityContext looks the following:

```
'name' => 'Tom, $lastName'
'lastName' => 'Peter'
```

now when I map the context on the template, I get

> hi, Tom, $lastName

whereas what I want to achieve is

> hi, Tom, Peter

Means I want to apply the changes incrementally instead of all at once. Anyone have done this before?

Comment: Well in my particular use case, its not as simple as Peter and Tom, its rather a bit more complicated. I have got several keys in my context and one of the key is the body of the page. Now the body itself is quite dynamic and the content is heavily personalised (like name, and other details). This personalised details has to be resolved later using the rest of the keys.

Answer (score 1):

`$name` doesn't contain a value, it's a template by itself, so it needs to be evaluated. So you need to use tools to render it:

- if you have access to the Velocity view tools, then use the [ViewRenderTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/view/ViewRenderTool.html) like this: `hi, $render.recurse("$name")`
- if you have only access to the Velocity generic tools, then you need to expose the context in itself (for instance under the `context` key) and use the [RenderTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/RenderTool.html) like this: `hi, $render.recurse($context, "$name")`
- otherwise, you have to go with your own evaluation tool, or change your implementation to avoid the need of a recursive evaluation.